# how to programmatically call the "click" of css

Tags: c#, javascript, html, css, webbrowser-control

I'm writing a C # program to automate the routine work. 
  Faced with the difficulty: 
On html page there is a text, when you click on that executes JavaScript. 
the text is in the

```
 <span class=myClass>Click me</span>
```

more cascading style sheets in the file for this class is EventListener odds press, which when clicked performs the function of java script file:

```
function (t){return typeof he===X||t&&he.event.triggered===t.type?e:he.event.dispatch.apply(u.elem,arguments)}
```

From a file javascript nothing is clear. He is the most obfuscated. How to programmatically call the click event?

Comment: Have you tried to get Element from Html Document of webbrowser? and clicked it by invokemember(..)?

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("myClass")[0].click()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest and most trouble-free solution was the analysis of http requests to the server and send the required data.